# Pandas:Count accumulated unique values based on another column

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, unique

I have a simple data frame with IDs and date, like below:

```
    'ID Date
     a  2009/12/1
     c  2009/12/1
     d  2009/12/1
     a  2010/4/1
     c  2010/5/1
     e  2010/5/1
     b  2010/12/1
     b  2012/3/1
     e  2012/7/1
     b  2013/1/1
    ...
    ...'
```

I need to count unique values by each month and accumulate them but not counting existing IDs. For instance

```
    `2009/12/1 3
     2010/4/1  3
     2010/5/1  4
     ... ...`
```

I created a loop but not working

```
       `for d in df['date'].drop_duplicates():
        c=df[df['date']<=d].ID.nunique()
        df2=DataFrame(data=c,index=d)`
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem? thanks

Comment: so if `a` appears twice in the same month, it is only counted once, correct?  Also, are all of your date listed as the first of the month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to write a for loop and use a set to hold the cumulative unique IDs:

```
cumcount = []
cumunique = set()
date = []
for k, g in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.Date)):
    cumunique |= set(g.ID)                  # hold cumulative unique IDs
    date.append(g.Date.iat[0])              # get the date variable for each group
    cumcount.append(len(cumunique))         # hold cumulative count of unique IDs

pd.DataFrame({"Date": date, "ID": cumcount})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your codes. I can't try it at the moment, but seems it will work. Actually i am still new to Python, can u give me some info about 'set'?

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. But still good to understand what is "set"

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `groupby()` rather than looping over your data frame.  After grouping by the date column, you can count the unique instances of ID using:

```
df.groupby('Date')['ID'].nunique()
```

Quick example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a' ,'2009/12/1'],
                   ['c' ,'2009/12/1'],
                   ['d' ,'2009/12/1'],
                   ['c' ,'2009/12/1'],
                   ['a' ,'2010/4/1'],
                   ['c' ,'2010/5/1'],
                   ['e' ,'2010/5/1']], columns = ['ID','Date'])

df.groupby('Date')['ID'].nunique()
# returns:
# Date
# 2009/12/1    3
# 2010/4/1     1
# 2010/5/1     2
```

Comment: I need to count unique IDs from the oldest date to current. group by only count unique ID for that period which can't meet my needs